# Gnu Radio and vlc result in RuntimeError?

Tags: vlc, gnuradio-companion

I am trying to make a stream (tried both .mp4 and .TS file)from vlc to GNU radio companion back to a different VLC windows with the use of UDP on a windows 10 PC.
The program is simple: 
UDP source(IP:127.0.0.1 + port:5003) to a UDPsink(IP: + port:5005)

At the VLC I use for receiving the stream: udp:\@:5005.
And for streaming port:5003 + IP:127.0.0.1 and a profile: Video-H.264+MP3(TS).
But when I try to run the program is get following error:
RuntimeError: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

I don't understand why I get this. I have given the VLC full control and run it as an administrator and I have even made a new rule in the firewall (Norton) to allow UDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. I just had to change the size of the load buffers in the UDP source to 1600 en in the sink to 1200 or 1300. There is still a problem the that there is to much data but think this is because my PC is to slow.

Answer (score 0):

try using the same port on both ends, i.e. udp:://127.0.0.1:5005 and check your permissions and firewall settings.